# I just updated to Https from Http, Should I change WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address in Wordpress Dashboard?

Tags: https

I have just updated my blog [technosamigos.com](https://technosamigos.com/) from http to https. I got the SSL via cPanel provided by Comodo. For me everything looks fine but one thing I see on popular results for 'http to https guide' on web is to change the website URL. Contradicting to this, I see lot of similar questions to this one, have gone through most of them and all have reported site went down after URL change.

Should I change WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address [URL] in Wordpress Dashboard from Settings > General? Currently they are set to http version.

Comment: Yes, you change the SITE and WP URL. Also, you have to change all URL's of images/scripts/stylesheets with http to https.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Amit. I did the first step, how can I change all URL's of images, scripts and stylesheets?

Comment: Most of your pages are working fine, you can check same using console of your web-browser.